# How to get "Description" from wikidata entry with SPARQL query?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

How can I extract the description for a given item label? For example, for Barack Obama (Q76) [link](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q76) there is a listed description: "44th president of the United States". How do I retreive this? I am able to extract the "label" using this:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> 
#Cats
SELECT ?label
WHERE 
{
  wd:Q76 rdfs:label ?label .
  FILTER (langMatches( lang(?label), "EN" ) )
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

(Although this gives me the same result 3 times...) How do I get the description as well?

Comment: Why don't you use the label service when you have it in your query? And it gives you the same result because there are 3 literals with different English flavour

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the label service is. I'm just getting familiarized with this method of querying.

Comment: The "label service" is this non-standard SPARQL extension which gives you label, description and alias for free by convention with a suffix to each variable name: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual#Label_service

Comment: Clealry, you need a variable to make use of it. Here we go: `SELECT ?itemLabel ?itemDescription
WHERE 
{ VALUES ?item {wd:Q76}
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}`

Comment: If you don't want to use this service, use `schema:description` as the property analogous to what you did with `rdfs:label`

Answer (score 5):

[In the manual mode of Wikidata label  service](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual#Label_service), you explicitly bind the label variables within the service call.

For example, with Barack Obama (Q76) entry, we can bind the label and the description.

```
PREFIX bd: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/> 
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> 
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#> 

SELECT ?obamaLabel ?obamaDesc
WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
    wd:Q76 rdfs:label ?obamaLabel .
    wd:Q76 schema:description ?obamaDesc .
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://linkedwiki.com/query/Get_Description_from_wikidata_entry_with_SPARQL_query)